# disallow access outside of file

Tags: c++

Now I know someone is going to say static or anon namespace without reading so let me just say no that is not what I'm looking for. What I am looking for is something that will allow me to kind of "quarantine" off a file in my code base so it can't access anything outside of that file so that if someone changes it it can't inadvertently screw things up elsewhere. Is this possible?

Comment: Are you looking to enforce this at compile time or run time?

Comment: What about library calls then ?

Comment: What service does that file provide to the rest of the world?  Normally, if the file provides a service, it will have to be compiled, and if someone changes it badly, it can screw up the code that uses the services it provides.  If it doesn't provide a service to the rest of the world, it is already isolated and nothing will be using it, so there can be no harm done.  All of this is normally enforced by policies about the code base (hide it in an obscure directory), etc.

Comment: Doing it the other way round, and properly encapsulating everything else would be the traditional method.

Comment: IMO this question is not "unclear what they're asking" so much as "not the typical 'fix my syntax error`."  I think it should be reopened.  If it really should be put on hold, it might be because it's "primarily opinion based" but not unclear IMO.

Comment: I'd agree that it's unclear - for instance, if the rest of the code doesn't access that file at all, then removing it from the codebase entirely or setting it to read-only would be obvious solutions. If the rest of the code *does* access that file, then asking how one can access code without any difference in behavior if that code changes is a little puzzling.

Answer (score 4):

> What I am looking for is something that will allow me to kind of "quarantine" off a file in my code base so it can't access anything outside of that file so that if someone changes it it can't inadvertently screw things up elsewhere. Is this possible?

For the most part, no, not as a part of the C++ language.

In order to accomplish your goal, consider one/some of the following:

- Moving the code from your file into another library to reduce the likelihood of collateral damage
- Providing "guarantees" by testing with dynamic tools like `valgrind`, Purify, ASan ("Address sanitizer"), Electric Fence
- Making comments regarding the intended design of the code for this file ("isolated", "encapsulated", etc)
- Build-time restrictions: dump the preprocessed output from the source file, flagging cases where new `#include`s (ones outside of a whitelist, e.g.) show up.

Answer (score 2):

Have the file not include any headers from the rest of your project. Of course this doesn't protect against malicious coding, but then, neither does anything else in C++.